# Looping over an collection where the key is an ID, and the value is a user class

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my react component I am trying to display a select dropdown list by looping over my users collection:

```
{users.map(user => (
                <option value={user.id}>user.username</option>
              ))}
```

The problem I am having is that my users collection is actually keyed with the userId, and then the value is the actual user class.

How can I loop over this type of object?

```
users: {
  1: {
    account_id: 1,
    email: "john@example.com",
    id: 1,
    inserted_at: "2018-12-20T17:25:56",
    registration_status: 1,
    updated_at: "2018-12-20T17:25:56",
    username: "john"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could map over the users by using [`Object.values( users )`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values)

```
{ 
   Object.values( users ).map( user => (
    <option key={user.id} value={user.id}>user.username</option>
  )) 
}
```

This will map over all the inner values instead, and you don't have to use the indexer.

As a sample you could see this snippet

```js
const users = {
  1: {
    account_id: 1,
    email: "john@example.com",
    id: 1,
    inserted_at: "2018-12-20T17:25:56",
    registration_status: 1,
    updated_at: "2018-12-20T17:25:56",
    username: "john"
  }
};

Object.values( users ).map( user => console.log( user ) );
```

As rightly mentioned by Ionut Achim, when you are returning an array of items, make sure they have [unique key property](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys), to avoid side effects in your codes behavior ;)

Comment: Don't forget to add the `key` for each option.

Comment: @IonutAchim Right, I added it with a link to the documentation of react, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want `Object.values`:

```js
const users = {
  1: {
    account_id: 1,
    email: "john@example.com",
    id: 1,
    inserted_at: "2018-12-20T17:25:56",
    registration_status: 1,
    updated_at: "2018-12-20T17:25:56",
    username: "john"
  }
}

console.log(Object.values(users))
```

i.e.

```
{Object.values(users).map(user => (
  <option value={user.id}>user.username</option>
))}
```